# Distribuir php como ejecutable

Tags: php

Buenas estoy haciendo algunos script php sin bases de datos, y necesito mostrarlo a aalguien; pero no cuento en estos momentos con un servidor web. Es por eso que quiero saber si hay manera de hacer que esos escript se conviertan en ejecutables o algo por el estilo, para que esa persona pueda verlo y probarlo en su PC; logicamente no puedo pedirle que instale un servicio como XAMP, etc.
Desde ya mil gracias a quien pueda darme una pista, en caso que se pueda hacer.
Saludos cordiales.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y probaste algo de todas las soluciones que hay por ahi en internet?

Comment: Hola, antes que nada tu pregunta no es válida por lo que comenta el amigo @gbianchi ahora si solo deseas mostrar puedes usar Ngrok y le das una URL temporal. Saludos

Comment: Es la primera vez que pregunto; y si, ya probé algunas cosas por eso acudo a esta comunidad. Podrían aclarme que tiene de malo la pregunta? porque es lo que necesito hacer. Nuevamente gracias.

Comment: No comentas que probaste.. entonces, como podemos saber si la respuesta que te van a dar sirve, o ya la probaste? siempre, se claro con lo que queres hacer, y todo lo que intentaste....

Comment: Si @gbianchi tenes razón. Disculpas por las molestias, seguiré indagando a ver que encuentro. Si consigo lo que busco lo compartiré aquí por si le sirve a alguien. Saludos cordiales.

Comment: Si lo encuentras, es mas que recomendable que respondas tu propia respuesta!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP no necesita instalación. Si es para **correr scripts** solo [bajas el zip](https://windows.php.net/download/), lo descomprimes en una carpeta, configuras bien las rutas en **php.ini** y ya está (obviamente la pc debe tener los [VCRedist](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170) necesarios).
Lo ejecutas como

```
X:\ruta\de\php.exe Y:\ruta\del\script.php
```

Podrías hacer un directorio con todos esos archivos (incluyendo los binarios php) y unos .bat para que no tenga que escribir las rutas.

Si necesitas un webserver *de emergencia*, no mucha gente sabe esto, pero PHP trae un [webserver incorporado](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.commandline.webserver.php) que puede servir para demostraciones o desarrollos rápidos.

```
X:\ruta\de\php.exe -S localhost:8000 -t Y:\ruta\de\htdocs
```

Comment: Ok, entiendo, necesito que la persona a la que le mando los script los pueda usar, sin tener que instalar un servidor local en su maquina. Veré lo del webserver de php, la verdad no sabía.

Comment: @CarlosGarcia no hay manera de ejecutar un script php sin tener el interprete de php en el equipo; recuerda que php no son binarios ejecutables o algo parecido... son archivos de texto que requieren ser interpretados.